# Python XML parsing with ignorance of the tag body

Tags: python, xml, linux

I want to parse an XML file in python and assert some tag orders. I have started with `ElementTree`. Here is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

And here is the `test.xml`:

```
<a>
<b>
for (i=0; i<10; i++){
    k++;
}
</b>
</a>
```

The problem is, the parser stucks at the `for statement` with the following error:

```
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 3, column 12
```

I need the parser to ignore the body of tags (ignoring anything comes inside the `<b></b>`). Is there a way to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your XML is invalid. Even BeautifulSoup can't handle it. The `<10` in your `for` loop is being treated as a tag, which is confusing the parser.

Comment: Oops! Should I double-quote entire body?

Comment: Learn about XML first instead of tinkering. You lack XML basics like CDATA sections.

Comment: You should replace `<` with `&lt;` or put the contents of `<b>` in a CDATA block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XML markup is invalid XML markup!

You need to enclose the offending text inside a CDATA section.

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp